# Add non-negativity constraint to a reverse optimization function

Tags: matrices, finance, bayesian, reverse-math

I am working with a model for portfolio management (Black-Litterman specifically) in finance. I have problems trying to impose a constraint where I want the values of a vector ($w_i$) to be non-negative.

And this is my reverse optimization function.

$$\mu = \delta \Sigma w, $$ where $\delta$ is a constant

$$ \Omega = \tau (P' \Sigma P), $$ where $P$ is a non-singular $3\times n$ matrix and $\Omega$ is a diagonal matrix with $0$'s in the off-diagonal positions

$$ \Pi = [(\tau \Sigma)^{-1} + P' \Omega P ]^{-1} [(\tau \Sigma)^{-1} \mu + P'\Omega^{-1} Q],$$ where $Q$ is a $1 \times 3$ vector

$$
w_i = \frac{1} \tau \Sigma ^{-1} \Pi 
$$

- $w_i$ is a $n \times 1$ vector
- $\Sigma$ is a $n \times n$ non-singular matrix
- $\Pi$ is a $n \times 1$ vector
- $\tau$ is a constant

Is it possible to add a constraint to this function such that all values in $w_i$ is non-negative?

Comment: While your problem's setup is surely clear to you, some important details need to be shared with your Readers.  By "reverse optimization" it appears that you are working backward from a value of some (unstated) objective function to get values $w_r$.  It is unclear how if the $w_r$ are determined by your formula, you would propose to "add a constraint".  Perhaps you have in mind conditions on the data $\Pi$ and $\Sigma$ which force a strictly positive solution $\vec w$?

Comment: Thank you. I thought the final formula was sufficient for my problem. I will add all of the formulas to the original post so it would be clear for everyone as well.

Comment: I have now edited the original post. Hope it is more clear now, and thanks for your patience. I have been tried to find a solution. A lot of papers mention the non-negativity constraint, but no formulas or solution are given for the problem.